# Associative array PHP, getting data starting from a known data

Tags: php, arrays

This is maybe very simple, but I got a little disaster trying to solve this problem. I have a associative array in PHP that looks like this:

```
$people= array (["Name" => "Sandra", "Age" => "21"], ["Name" => "Frank", "Age" => "34"], ["Name" => "Marc", "Age" => "56"]);
```

Now if I want to know the age of two known elements inside the array, lets say, Sandra and Frank. I tryed to do like this:

```
foreach($people as $i){
    foreach($i as $info => $v){
        if($info == "Name"){
            if($v == "Sandra" || $v == "Frank"){
                    echo $v." has ". $v;            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is: **Sandra has Sandra**. But this is of course not what should print. Can somebody let me understand this simple problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using two conventions of using arrays in PHP. Its sometimes become unclear, so use only one convention, for example:

```
$people= [["Name" => "Sandra", "Age" => "21"], ["Name" => "Frank", "Age" => "34"], ["Name" => "Marc", "Age" => "56"]]
```

or

```
$people= array(array("Name" => "Sandra", "Age" => "21"), array("Name" => "Frank", "Age" => "34"), array("Name" => "Marc", "Age" => "56"))
```

And there is solution for your problem:

```
foreach($people as $person)
    if($person['Name'] == "Sandra" || $person['Name'] == "Frank")
        echo $person['Name'] . ' has ' . $person['Age'];
```

Comment: Thx very much for the explanation and the clear answer

Answer (score 2):

Why 2 foreach loop, you can achive it by one foreach loop:

```
$people = array(["Name" => "Sandra", "Age" => "21"], ["Name" => "Frank", "Age" => "34"], ["Name" => "Marc", "Age" => "56"]);

foreach ($people as $v) {


    if ($v["Name"] == "Sandra" || $v["Name"] == "Frank") {
        echo $v["Name"] . " has " . $v["Age"];
        echo "<br />";
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Sandra has 21
Frank has 34
```

Comment: I upvoted for optimization, I just wrote my answer as it is to respect his way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$flag = false;
foreach($people as $i){
    foreach($i as $info => $v){
        if($info == "Name"){
            if($v == "Sandra" || $v == "Frank"){
                echo $v." has "; 
                $flag = true;
            }
            else
                $flag = false;
        }
        if($info == "Age" && $flag){

            echo $v;          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THX for the answer, but is only printig the age of Sandra

Comment: @DennysGonzalez just replace the third `elseif` to be `if`